# Pyinstaller for Python code that uses T5 transformer

Tags: pyinstaller, spacy, huggingface-transformers

I have a python code that uses transformer models downloaded from huggingface (specifically T5 and NER) . I am trying to create a .exe using pyinstaller. However, running into multiple errors despite providing hooks.

Any solution to this?

error as below:

importlib.metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for The 'huggingface- hub>=0.19.3,<1.0' distribution was not found and is required by this application.
try: pip install transformers -U or pip install -e '.[dev]' if you're working with git main

checked through pip list, i already have huggingface-hub installed.

Comment: Maybe check out https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5878

Comment: It's not telling you you don't have huggingface-hub installed.  It's telling you that you don't have the version it wants.

Comment: Hi @possum, the version requirement is also satisfied. It is 0.21.4 which is >0.19.3